# python flask query params

Tags: python, mysql, flask, backend

I am trying to get datas from `mysql` db using python `flask` and I have a question when I want to list of these datas. for example, this is my python code:

```py
@app.route('/getallbyparent', defaults = {'page':1})
@app.route('/getallbyparent/<int:page>')
def getallbyparent(page):
    parent = request.args.get('parent')
    limit = 5
    startat = (page -1) * limit
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM yenitable WHERE parent LIKE %s",[parent])
    total = cursor.rowcount #toplama veri sayisi
    print(total)
    totalpage = math.ceil(total/limit)# toplam sayfa sayisi
    print(totalpage)
    next_page = page + 1 
    previous_page = page - 1
    sorgu = "SELECT * FROM yenitable WHERE parent = %s limit %s, %s;"
    cursor.execute(sorgu,(parent,startat,limit))
    veriler = list(cursor.fetchall())
    cursor.close()
    return render_template("/getallbyparent.html",datas=veriler , next_page = next_page ,previous_page = previous_page,totalpage=totalpage,limit = limit,parent=parent)
```

And my html pagination codes:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="/getallbyparent?parent={{parent}}/{{previous_page}}" aria-label="Previous">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/getallbyparent?parent={{parent}}/1">1</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/getallbyparent?parent={{parent}}/2">2</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/getallbyparent?parent={{parent}}/3">3</a></li>
      <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="/getallbyparent?parent={{parent}}/{{next_page}}" aria-label="Next">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <label style="font-size:large;">totalpage : {{totalpage}}</label><br>
  <label style="font-size:large;">per page: {{limit}}</label>
```

I am searching parent values , for example `parent=parent1` , `parent1 =` my value from input. And I wanna show them on pages per 5 rows. I want it to be like this, `getallbyparent?parent=parent1/2,3,4,5,6,7,8` to 8 pages. Like this. Can u help me about it? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. You can always send list with many values to template and use loop `{% for %}` in template

Comment: i did it actually. I use for I just want to go to second page and i can not do it.

Comment: if you did it then show it in question - we can't read in your mind - and maybe you made some small mistake which we could simply correct.

Comment: I'm not sure but you need page number before `?` like `getallbyparent/2?parent=parent1`

Answer (score 0):

Now I see you have problem with links in `"pagination"`

Parameters `?` have to be at the end of link in HTML

```
href="/getallbyparent/2?parent={{parent}}"
href="/getallbyparent/3?parent={{parent}}"
href="/getallbyparent/4?parent={{parent}}"
href="/getallbyparent/5?parent={{parent}}"
href="/getallbyparent/6?parent={{parent}}"
href="/getallbyparent/7?parent={{parent}}"
href="/getallbyparent/8?parent={{parent}}"
```

Comment: Yes. it should be like this. it does not matter if it will be end or beginning of the ling. i want to go to another page like this. when i searched it is like /getallbyparnet/parent=parent1 AND i want to see another pages for parent1. Thank u btw.

Comment: maybe all your problem is wrong SQL query - usually it needs `LIMIT` with `OFFSET` but you use only `LIMIT`. Other problem can be that `total` you count with `parent LIKE %s` but you get data using `parent = %s` and this may gives different result.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: if you put it at the beginning then it may thread `"parent1/2"` as value for `parent=`, not page number. And then it will use default page `1`

Comment: But it works. i just can't go to another pages. actually idk how to code it. When i did not use ?parent=parent1 , like /getall/1 2 3  4 5, it works and i can go another pages but when i used searching , it does not work because i did not find the right python code probably.

Comment: did you run flask in console to error messages ? maybe your `parent` generate erorr and it can't go to next page. OR you put wrong data and it always gives you first page, As I said: maybe use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you really have on variables - because all your problem can be inside `getallbyparent()` but you try to fix HTML.

Comment: i use them and probably the problem is that it can not go to next page. and idk what code i can use. do u know something about it ? pagination with search?

Comment: as I said: first use `print()` to see what you really have in variables. Your HTML looks correct, and searching other method is useless if you don't know what is the real problem. And all problem can be that it get exactly the same data from database and it display the same data on next page. But I still think that `/getallbyparent?parent=parent1/2` is wrong and it has to be `/getallbyparent/2?parent=parent1`

Comment: I tested flask with `/getallbyparent?parent=parent1/2` and it is really wrong - it always gives `page 1` and parent `"parent1/2"`. It has to be `/getallbyparent/2?parent=parent1`.

Comment: do you know how can i do it ? idk what code i can use there to make it /getallbyparent/1,2,3,4?parent=parent1. ? Thank you so much.

Comment: in HTML you set `href="/getallbyparent?parent={{parent}}/2"` but you it has to be `href="/getallbyparent/2?parent={{parent}}"` - with `/2` before `?parent={{parent}}`. That's all. And the same for `href` to other pages

Comment: I added `href="/getallbyparent/2?parent={{parent}}"` to answer.